# How to do the tilling in 3d tiles

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JavaScript file for converting cityGML data to 3d tiles format. But I can only convert the cityGML data to 3d tiles format in one b3dm file without children tiles. How to do the tilling to creat tiles with Quadtrees or Octrees?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have to manually divide your cityGML data into different levels, and then convert them respectively into b3dm files. As for the model division, you can divide the model according to the location(such as top, bottom, left, right) or significance (such as landmark in level 0 and others in level 1, etc.). Then the quadtree, octree part can be done automatically in cesiumjs.